# Equivalent Resistance?

Tags: resistors

[image: How do you find the equivalent resistance here?]

How do you find the equivalent resistance here? (I realized it's a Wheatstone bridge, but it's unbalanced, so that doesn't help.) I tried using Kirchhoff's laws, but there is no cell given.

Comment: No. Just practising,

Comment: This might help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform#Simplification_of_networks

Comment: If you connected +1V to point X and 0V to point Y how much current would flow? If you can work out the answer to that then you can work out the resistance between X and Y.

Comment: This combination consists an unbalanced Weaston bridge, so there is a current from B to E and definately you can not solve with series/parallel method. You can use mesh analysis or Y-Δ transform http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform. Another interesting proposal is here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22252/resistor-circuit-that-isnt-parallel-or-series but it is not proofed by anyone yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like irreducible network - network which does not contain series or parallel connections that can be reduced.

You can add some voltage source to X and Y terminals and do mesh analysis.

It is explained in [Wikipedia mesh analysis article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis),
and also in [this video by Darryl Morrel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZVHHRTMKwY) so I will not explain it here.

Comment: This can be found pretty easily using delta-to-wye transformations.

Comment: Yea, but I saw that Null suggested that in comments, so I provided diffrent (more universal) approach.

Comment: @Leponzo I added youtube link to really nice tutorial about mesh analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Y-Δ transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) and find 7 Ohm.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frYjHj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After applying the transform technique for R1, R3 and R4, the circuit is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAtUQ7.png)</sup>